# Returning an image to display in browsers

Tags: php, image

I've written a PHP script to return an image but the browser can't display the returned one. Would you guys please tell me what's wrong?

```
<?php
    $file='demo.gif';
    if(file_exists($file)){
        header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64');
        $data=base64_encode(get_file_contents($file)); 
        header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($data));
        echo $data;
    }
    else
        echo 'No such file';
?>
```

Comment: Why are you using base64_encode? You're just enlarging the size of the image for nothing.

Comment: You are loading a gif and setting headers for a jpeg.

Comment: @Truth: Our client's requirement specification do require that. :) Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @vascowhite: Oh gosh! You're totally right. What a stupid mistake! Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you're telling the browser that the `.gif` file is a JPEG.

You also typo'd `file_get_contents`.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a very good reason for it, don't base64 encode your image data.  Output the raw data instead.

Also `get_file_contents` should probably be `file_get_contents()`. Remove the `header()` command and activate [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to see any such errors.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed it with your suggestions. Thanks all! :)
Here's the modified code.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
$image= file_get_contents('http://localhost/no_img.gif');
echo $image;?>
```